# How can I get all records for the week using date strings not date objects?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table in the database where the records contain a start_date and an end_date. An example of the data format is:

```
"13/03/2020"
```

How can I fetch all records for the week? I have tried the code below. However, it does not return any data.

```
$date = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/Y');
$dateInWeek = Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->format('d/m/Y');

$holidays = Holiday::where('start_date', '>=', $date)
 ->where('end_date', '<=', $dateInWeek)->get();
```

Comment: What are `start_date` and `end_date` columns types ?

Comment: varchar @matiaslauriti

Comment: I think what you are trying to do will never work, because you are using `>=` on a `varchar`, both columns should be `timestamp`...

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. Thank you for your time @matiaslauriti.

Comment: You can try `Carbon::getHolidays` which uses the [package](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/business-time)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use string when you can use date / datetime column type.

But that being said - it's not always up-to us to be able to change DB structure.

**Solution 1**

Depending on what SQL you are using there is usually function to cast string to date.
For example MySQL: `STR_TO_DATE(string, format)`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

**Solution 2**

You can make array containing all dates of week using Carbon.
then in query: `->whereIn('start_date', $datesArray)->whereIn('end_date', $datesArray)`

I'd still suggest changing column type to date if possible

Comment: I think we're going to take the time to change the column to datetime, I feel like this will also be helpful in the future. Thank you for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0):

Probably correct solution is to change string to datetime in db, if it is not an opinion then you can create custom function in database that will handle strings in way you want.

Comment: I think I may have to spend the time to change the columns types and feed the data back in. Thank you for the confirmation @Aleksej.